# Ionic Platform custom midle tab

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic-view

So i having problem to customise in bottom tabs the middle, i want to make middle tab height bigger then other tabs, so i cant find the way to customise it. It would be nice if there would be somebody that can help with this.
Link for editing  [link](http://goo.gl/FDk6NQ). And wanted result [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOINn.png).

Tried separately change the hight but, there are a feeling that flex box doesn't allow to tab go out of content.

Answer (score 0):

Inherit the CSS class that holds the icon in the middle and add your custom properties.